# Can't import the encoder code for fine tuning GPT-2

Tags: python, path, nlp, init, gpt-2

I'm trying to reproduce the example from this article: https://medium.com/@ngwaifoong92/beginners-guide-to-retrain-gpt-2-117m-to-generate-custom-text-content-8bb5363d8b7f

The example code is from the following repo: https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2

After installing the requirements and downloading the model, the following step is to train the model, for which this code has to be executed:

```
python encode.py lyric.txt lyric.npz
```

The issue here is that this requires to import the following modules:

```
import argparse
import numpy as np

import encoder
from load_dataset import load_dataset
```

Where **encoder** and **load_dataset** are on a child directory:

```
|--encode.py
 --src
   |--encoder.py
   |--load_dataset.py
```

This generates the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encoder'
```

I tried creating the `__init__.py` files and importing them as

**src.encoder** and **src.load_dataset** but that those not work either.

In the medium post the author proposes to move the file **encoder.py** to src and execute the code from there, the issue there is that doing it breaks the relative path for the model too and although I handled that the issue with the paths keeps going for other files as well.

Comment: please accept if it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Make an empty file named `__init__.py` inside the `src` folder.
2. Import `encoder` as:`from src import encoder`

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source of `encode.py` ([here](https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2/blob/finetuning/encode.py)). At the very beginning, there is this:

```
# Usage:
#  PYTHONPATH=src ./encode.py <file|directory|glob> /path/to/output.npz
#  PYTHONPATH=src ./train --dataset /path/to/output.npz
```

Please try again, setting `PYTHONPATH` as they suggest you do.

Answer (score 1):

none of that worked for me. however what i did was i installed python 3.6 because tensorflow is compatible with this version, I installed the following requirements :

```
h5py==3.1.0      
idna==2.10       
protobuf==3.13.0     
pywin32==228        
regex==2020.10.28 
requests==2.24.0     
tensorboard==2.3.0      
tensorflow==2.3.1      
tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0      
tqdm==4.51.0     
urllib3==1.25.11
```

updated the visual C++ for tensorflow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads and run the encode.py and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the 100% correct way to do this but to get around settign a pythonpath, you can copy the files into the src/ directory from the gpt-2/ directory.

So after you are in the gpt-2 directory you can run the following in your cmd line.

```
cp encode.py src\
cp train.py src\
cp models\ src\
```

If you do all of this then cd into src/ and run:

```
python filetoencode.txt filetoencode.npz
```

you should now have an encoded file and be able to move onto the next steps in the blog post.

Enjoy and have fun with the gpt-2 :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old topic, but this worked for me:
Change encode.py imports to

```
import src.encoder as encoder
from src.load_dataset import load_dataset
```

Then you can run

```
 py encode.py trainingfile.txt training.npz
```